# Find the line of the match character

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I would like to see the line where a character exists.

The expected answer would be the 4-row numbers which include the character BTC.

```
library(stringr)
library(quantmod)  
symbols <- stockSymbols()
symbols <- symbols[,1]
    u <- symbols 
    a <- "BTC"
    
    str_detect(a, u)
    table(str_detect(a, u))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `grepl` with `which`

```
which(grepl(a, u))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either use the tidyverse way, using the `filter()` function:

```
filter(dataset, column == "BTC")
```

Or using the `grep()` function from base R:

```
grep("BTC", dataset$column)
```

That will give you the index (*i.e.* place) of what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to get the index where pattern `a` occurs.

```
#Index
grep(a, u)
#[1] 3437

#Value
grep(a, u, value = TRUE)
#[1] "EBTC"
```

Using `stringr` :

```
library(stringr)

#Index
str_which(u, a)

#Value
str_subset(u, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option might be `which` + `regexpr` (but I think `grep` or `grepl` is obviously more efficient and straightforward)

```
which(regexpr(a, u)>0)
```